# Android studio 3.0 error, how can I get rid of it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I just update my android studio to 3.0 now, but when I try to build apk on my project, it's shows following error:

**Project depends on com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0, so it must also depend (as a provided dependency) on com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.0**

My build.gradle is like that:

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':lpd')
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0-alpha2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.4.0'
    compile files('libs/zxing_2.3.0.jar')
    compile(name: 'hwwearableservice-release', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'
}
```

Anything wrong with it?

Comment: can you paste the full stack trace

Comment: I change to compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0', and add provided 'com.google.wearable.support:wearable:2.0.0', it is ok for now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the new [`gradle dependency instruction`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations) the `compile` has been deprecated so for libraries use `api` and use the latest stable lib version as `2.1.0`

and since the version is a stable release so

```
api 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.1.0'
```

or it's better to use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.1.0'
```

---

`implementation`

> if an implementation dependency changes its API, Gradle recompiles
>   only that dependency and the modules that directly depend on it. Most
>   app and test modules should use this configuration.

`api`

> When a module includes an api dependency, it's letting Gradle know
>   that the module wants to transitively export that dependency to other
>   modules, so that it's available to them at both runtime and compile
>   time. `This configuration behaves just like compile (which is now`
>   `deprecated), and you should typically use this only in library`
>   `modules. That's because, if an api dependency changes its external`
>   `API, Gradle recompiles all modules that have access to that dependency`
>   `at compile time`